# restore (target) window is empty in macrium reflect boot cd

Tags: window, target, restore, is-empty

macrium reflect, version 5.1xx free has a bug.
some users have the same problem.

http:// wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=311023

http:// support.macrium.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=3828

http:// support.macrium.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4766

wheni boot-ed from linux rescue cd, then i choose the image file, but when clicked next, the Destination window is empty, and i can not select the target disk - in that window there is shown nothing to select. it is empty!

in a macrium forum, i have found one answer ( but havent tested): users need to choose IDE (in Disk Controller, inside BIOS).

BUT! Macrium  Rescue CD version 4.xxx SEES EVERYTHING NORMALLY! and i used version 4.xx's rescue cd to succeed!

is there any other fix for version 5.xx?

Answer (score 0):

here is Macirum Restore  [RescueCD for version 4.xx](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz7qe_olclTwU0ZmVFpOYTdlLVU/edit?usp=sharing), and you'd better to use that, if you cant see your drives in destination window list.

I dont know if developers will fix that.. But the version 4 shows the drives in the restore/target window. it is a fun - why version 5 cant see that?...